# Install JHipster Registry error: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath

Tags: java, node.js, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I try to install JHipster Registry
https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry

I have installed java, node, Yeoman, yarn and windows-build-tools.
When I try to use comand mvnw on this application I have this error:

I tried t0 reinstall webpack, but same error...

```
2019-04-08 11:35:54.186 ERROR 10072 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.j.s.i.w.WadlApplicationContextImpl   : Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:177)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:364)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:508)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:465)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:366)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.<init>(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:107)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:100)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:744)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:80)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:589)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:554)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:596)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.createUndertowServer(UndertowServletWebServer.java:200)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.start(UndertowServletWebServer.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at io.github.jhipster.registry.JHipsterRegistryApp.main(JHipsterRegistryApp.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:148)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
        at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:174)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're using Java 11, and only Java 8 is supported by the current version of JHipster Registry. If you use Java 8, everything should work as expected.

Comment: But I see that the Jhipster 6 is available just for java 11+, so If I use Jhipster 6 what should I use instead of JHipster Registry?
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/04/java-11-java-12-jhipster-oidc

Comment: JHipster 6 is available as a beta. You should still be able to use JHipster Registry with Docker Compose if you create a gateway. There will be a version of JHipster Registry released with Java 11 support, it just hasn’t happened yet.

Comment: I was using JDK-12 and could open the login page, but couldn't login. I changed java to JDK-8 and it is working now.